# RawImage texture change event?

Tags: unity, textures, gui, ui-design

I have a `RawImage` and an `AspectRatioFitter` attached to it so I want to change the aspect ratio to fit the image in the texture field of the raw image.
But I need to avoid checking for it in the update as much as possible.
Is there an event for when the texture of a RawImage element has changed? Something like `OnTextureChanged()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a script responsible for changing the Texture instead of calling `rawImage.texture`. You will be able to raise an event when the texture changes thanks to this.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[System.Serializable]
public class FloatEvent : UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent<float> { };

public class RawImageManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Drag & Drop the RawImage component
    [SerializeField]
    private RawImage target ;

    // Select the `AspectRatio` component and the `aspectRatio` dynamic variable
    [SerializeField]
    private FloatEvent onAspectRatioChanged ;

    public Texture Texture
    {
        get { return target.texture ; }
        set
        {
             target.texture = value ;
            if( onAspectRatioChanged != null )
                onAspectRatioChanged.Invoke( value.width / value.height ) ;
        }
    }    
}
```

And then, call `GetComponent<RawImageManager>().Texture = texture ;` instead of `GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = texture ;`